# C# GDI - How to check if a Pixel is opaque or not?

Tags: c#, gdi, pixel, alpha

I am using a method to get a pixel of the image to check if this point is transparent or not. I am using GetPixel that returns a System.Drawing.Color with a 32bit color info.

This struct have the "A" property where I can get the alpha value of pixel, according to this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.a.aspx).

Code:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path))
{
    Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
    if (pixel.A == 0)
        // This is a fully transparent pixel
    else
        // This is not a fully transparent pixel
}
```

How are the correct way to check if a pixel is opaque or not?

Comment: opaque is 255 for the alpha channel.

Comment: I agree, and this is explicit on MSDN article, but I never got this value. With PNG and GIF images I get a maximum of 86 for this channel, and with JPEG images that are full opaque I getting other not fixed values.

Comment: FWIW: JPEG image files cannot represent transparency. I think JPEG2000 format can, but not the original JPEG.  I don't know why bmp.GetPixel would return garbage in the alpha channel for JPEG though.

Comment: Also note that GetPixel is ok for one or two pixel tests, but if you are going to be testing a lot of pixels you want to use direct memory access to the bitmap scanlines. GetPixel() is horrifically slow, in part because GetPixel always converts the actual pixel data from the native pixel format in the image to the canonical 32bpp RGBA format that GetPixel returns. Accessing the bitmap pixel memory directly requires more work, but you'll get much better performance and better fidelity working with the actual pixel memory.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. Actually I am reading only the first pixel to test. I can check the file extension to avoid JPGs, but I would like to a better solution, if there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the alpha channel the values are:

```
Opaque = 255
Translucent = 1-254
Transparent = 0
```

Comment: You are right, I had a mistake on my bitmaps. I edited to remove wrong content. Thank you.